# Rmarkdown setting the position of kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have the following issue, once knitting the Rmarkdown in Rstudio to PDF, my tables appear not in the position where they are in Rmarkdown file, but on the top of the page. I tried to add:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{float}
```

and

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(... fig.pos = "H")
```
````

But it didn't work. R and Rstudio run on Linux, the LaTeX engine is "pdflatex"

Fully reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{float}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.align = "center", dev = "cairo_pdf", fig.pos = "H")
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

\newpage

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

```{r}    
kable(cars %>% filter(cars$speed>=23), caption = "Speed vs distance")
```
````

Comment: It seems like the figure environment is only added when you defined a caption using `fig.cap`. Then the positioning parameter should be used as expected.

Comment: The solution was, deleting the `caption="..."` in `kable ()`, once deleted, the positioning began to work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can replace "hold_position" from claudius answer with "HOLD_position":

````
```{r}    
kable(cars %>% filter(cars$speed>=23), caption = "Speed vs distance") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```
````

As mentionned in the kableExtra package:

> if you find hold_position is not powerful enough to literally PIN your table in the exact position, you may want to use HOLD_position, which is a more powerful version of this feature. For those who are familiar with TeX, hold_position uses[!h] and HOLD_position uses [H] and the float package.

ref: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

You may also want to control figure position by adding fig.pos='H' to the figure chunk header.

Comment: Yes, it was crucial to `fig.pos='H'` AND `latex_options = "HOLD_position"` at the same time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

To fix the table position in your latex document, you don't need include header options nor set opts_chunk configs.  To do that you should specify the `latex_options` as `HOLD_position` by adding the `kable_styling()` function in the `kable` [[1](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)].

So the last chunk will be:

````r
```{r}    
kable(cars %>% filter(cars$speed>=23), caption = "Speed vs distance") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")
```
````

Comment: I tried to do this, but all the tables go to the end of my document. Is there another solution or method to hold the tables at the same location

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach for setting the position of a kable object for R Markdown Latex or Beamer output would be to include the table in a "textblock" environment, as posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32661/how-to-locate-figures-with-x-y-specified-location-in-a-presentation).

The YAML would include:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
  \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
  \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
```

The R code chunk (preceded and followed by the latex code for the "textblock") would look like:

````
\begin{textblock}{}(21.5, 51.5)
\footnotesize
```{r}    
kable(cars %>% filter(cars$speed>=23), caption = "Speed vs distance") 
```
\end{textblock}
````

This approach allows for a more fine tuned positioning of the kable output on the page, or beamer slide.