# In RMarkdown, why is the kable table printing below the header here?

Tags: r, header, r-markdown, cat, kable

I'm trying to generate a report with each row of a tibble printing vertically in a table on its own page using a for loop.  The tables are printing fine, but I want to put headers at the top of each page (and eventually, text).  Since the line of code to print the header (which appears as a header in my own document but not in my reprex, not sure why) is above the line of code to print the table, using kable, I expect the header to print above the table.  I suspect kable is doing something I don't understand behind the scenes but I cannot determine what.

What am I doing wrong, and how may I print headers at the top of each page?

I've provided below: a screenshot of the current output.

Relevant portion:

````
---
title: "kable-order-reprex"
author: "Rob Creel"
date: "6/4/2021"
output: pdf_document
---
 
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(kableExtra)
```
 
 
```{r chunk1, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {
  # Generate Table
  mtcars %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    stack() %>%
    select(ind, values) %>%
    kable(col.names = NULL) %>%
    kable_styling() -> my_table
 
  cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
 
  # Print Header
  cat(paste0("## ", mtcars %>% rownames() %>% extract2(i)))
 
  # Print Table
  print(my_table)
  cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
}
```
````

Pic of mis-ordered output.:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Maybe you can share the Markdown code through https://pastebin.com/ or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell everything is working as intented. The problem is [float management in LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions).

You can change the behaviour of the kable output by setting the argument `latex_options` in `kable_styling()`. E.g.

```
mtcars %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  stack() %>%
  select(ind, values) %>%
  kable(col.names = NULL) %>%
  #Use either "hold_position" or "HOLD_position"
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position") -> my_table
```

`hold_position` corresponds to `h`, while `HOLD_position` is `H`, [(read more about float options here)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures), where `H` is stricter than `h` and forces the position of the float output to be at the position where it is in the code. Also see `?kable_styling` (`latex_options` entry)

See similar question with answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153537/rmarkdown-setting-the-position-of-kable)