# R Markdown, kable_styling(latex_options="HOLD_position") not working

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a problem that I've seen several times on here, but the usual solutions aren't working. I can't share all of my code due to some PHI concerns, but I'll try to share as much as I can.

**The problem**

My kable tables are showing up below the respective headers.

Example code:
[image]

Example output:
[image]

**What I've tried**

So there are already a few answers on here about similar problems, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153537/rmarkdown-setting-the-position-of-kable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841636/in-rmarkdown-why-is-the-kable-table-printing-below-the-header-here?noredirect=1&lq=1) and it seems like most of them have you add some sort of

```
%>%kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```

snippet at the end of each bit of code.  Problem is, as you can see I did that and it didn't work.
I also have tried it with/without

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = "H")
```

up at the very top of the document. Still no dice.

One more thing that is weird is that there were a couple tables lower in the document which DID go into the right spot when I added the bit about hold_position.  Not sure why those worked and the others didn't.  Am I missing something?

I did see in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153537/rmarkdown-setting-the-position-of-kable), one of the comments mentioned that deleting the caption helped so I tried that (because the tables that worked in mine didn't have captions, so I figured maybe that was it)....   whether I left the captions or not it stayed put.

One other thing I noticed was that some of the tables that worked had text/photos in those sections prior to the table, like so:
[image]

So when I added some random text prior to the tables that weren't showing up in the right spot, they did show up correctly.  (Pictured below) Problem is, I don't want to have to add text there.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's solve it with the pure LaTeX ;)

````
---
title: "Test Table"
date: '2021-11-11'

header-includes: 
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{caption}

output:
  pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
tab1<- head(mtcars) %>% kbl()
```

\begin{table}[H]
\captionof{table}{Table, stay here!}
`r tab1`
\end{table}
````

[image]

Comment: I'm sure the problem is on my end, but right now when I try that it fails while knitting and I get the error: "undefined control sequence \captionof {table}{Table, stay here!}"

Comment: Oops, probably had something to do with me not remembering to do the "include package caption" thing at the top.

Comment: @JoeCrozier Yes ;) Now is all right?

Comment: Yup! Works great

Comment: @JoeCrozier And I should warn, make a caption with ```\captionof{}```. With ```kbl(caption = " ")``` and this "construction" you will be received an error. Good luck ;)